# Vue js does not bind values to form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, binding

I'm new to Vuejs but I'm trying to make a simple login form with it.

So I tried out this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" :value="email">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="email">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" :value="password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
        <script>
        const App = {
            date(){
                return {
                    email: 'example@roocket.ir',
                    password: '123456'
                }
            }
        };

        Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So as you can see I have used the CDN and successfully called the `#app` but I tried returning `password` and `email` values which are called from the script in the inputs however they are not shown in the form:

[image]

And this is the expected result:

[image]

And in the Console I get this:

```
vue@next:1616 [Vue warn]: Property "email" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <App>

vue@next:1616 [Vue warn]: Property "password" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <App>
```

So what's going wrong here?

How can I properly bind the input values from vuejs to the html (without using TwoWayBinding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error you're getting is caused by misspelling the `data()` function to `date()`. This causes `password` and `email` to not be defined in your component.

That typo aside, you should follow @Lissy93's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73765751/1891677) and use [v-model](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-model) instead of `:value`.
You might find [form-input-bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#form-input-bindings) useful.

I'd also strongly advise not to use `vue@next` at this point. Replace it with `vue`.
`vue@next` used to point to Vue 3 when Vue 2 was the default version but now Vue 3 is the default version.
Your import might cause your app to break when Vue 4 comes out, as it's probably going to be published as `vue@next`, if Vue 4 has breaking changes across any features your app uses.

Comment: I should have spotted that typo, +1 to your answer. And good advice re Vue@next

Answer (score 1):

#### Vue 2

Use `v-model` instead of `value`

Here's a working example:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'memite7760-demo',
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" v-model="email">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" v-model="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div>
  Username: {{ email }}, Password: {{ password }}
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Vue 3

As [pointed out by @tao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73766658/979052), you have a small typo: `date` should be `data`. He also gives some good advice re imports

Again, here's a working example:

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      email: 'example@roocket.ir',
      password: '123456'
    }
  }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" v-model="email">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" v-model="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  Email: {{email}}, Pass: {{password}}
</div>
```

Comment: Please note OP is using Vue 3. Perhaps you should update your snippet to it as well, especially since the syntax doesn't have to change. Using Vue 2 might lead future visitors to think your answer is outdated.

Comment: @tao - He did say he was using Vue-2, and it's got the Vue 2 tag, which is why I posted the answer in Vue 2, in above comment. But I can definitely add a Vue 3 version, if that would be helpful.

Comment: Their import says `vue@next`. That has been resolving Vue 3 for more than a year now. They might be thinking they're using Vue 2, possibly because they use Options API (which works perfectly fine in Vue 3), but I assure you they're not. :)